# Text not completely justified? Space between letters

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to recreate a PDF file to look exactly the same. Now I managed to get all equations and everything correct. But the formatting is abit off, in the original document there is more space between letters in certain places.

I've read many posts on this and other forums, PDF files explaining features etc but can't find a solution to my problem, that's why I'm posting my question here!

Original document look like this:
[image: Original]

My document look like this:
[image: Mydocument]

It shows in the second sentence, very subtle but obvious when you compared the documents on top of eachother. (My document has showframes on because I thought my margins were off thats the reason for the black bars)

This occurs on multiple places throughout the document and I have no idea why.
Any help would be appriciated because I've been trying to fix it for the past two hours without success.

Configuration code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, a4wide]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
```

EDIT: Sorry for breaking the rules, removed my post and edited first post instead.

Here is some of the code were the error exist in text:

```
\begin{document}
\section{The Koch Snowflake}
The \emph{Koch snowflake}, one of the first fractals, is based on work by the Swedish mathe\-matician Helge von Koch~\cite{koch}. It is what we get if we start with an equilateral triangle 
\begin{figure}[h] \label{koch}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{snowflake.jpg}
  \caption{The initial equilateral triangle and the refinement of the Koch snowflake after one, two, and three iterations.}
\end{figure} \\
and repeat the following an infinite number of times:
\begin{quote}
 \textit{Divide all the line segments into three segments of equal length. Then draw, for each middle line segment, an equilateral triangle that has the middle segment as its base and points outward. Finally, remove all middle segments.}
\end{quote}
Figure~\ref{koch} shows the first iterations in the construction.
%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you getting `Overfull \hbox` warnings?

Comment: Do you mean more space between *words* or between letters *within* words? The most obvious difference here is that in the second example, the second line is not right justified. That naturally leads to less interword space.

Answer (score 3):

It is rather easy to find examples that produce your problem. E.g. an additional empty line before the following text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, a4wide]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

The \emph{Koch Snowflake}, one of the first fractals, is based on the work of the Swedish mathe\-matician Helge von Koch [1]. It is what we get if we start with an equilateral triangle
\rule{3cm}{3cm}

The \emph{Koch Snowflake}, one of the first fractals, is based on the work of the Swedish mathe\-matician Helge von Koch [1]. It is what we get if we start with an equilateral triangle

\rule{3cm}{3cm}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different `\parfillskip` could be a cause too. But without more context and code one can only guess.